# Get AccessToken to Microsoft Graph from Azure App Service Easy Auth

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .NET core application hosted on `Azure App Service`. The application is secured with `Azure App Service Authentication`.

I need to get an **access token** to access Microsoft Graph.

Since I have `Azure App Service Authentication` turned on, and all the users that access the web application should already be authenticated, I was wondering if it is possible to get the **access token** from `/.auth/me` or `Request.Headers["x-ms-token-aad-access-token"]`.

### [image: Azure App Service Auth]

I tried to follow the example posted on [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/01/19/using-azure-commercial-aad-authentication-and-graph-api-in-azure-government-web-app-powershell-automation/)
, where I configured my `additionalLoginParams` `/config/authsettings` to `["resource=https://graph.windows.net"]` (or `["resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"]` as per Rohit suggestion), which in turn should give me an access token to MS Graph either via `/.auth/me` on client side or `Request.Headers["x-ms-token-aad-access-token"]` on C#.

However I checked both server side and client side, and there were no access token found. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I see that you're specifying `resource=https://graph.windows.net` which corresponds to older Azure AD Graph API (different than newer Microsoft Graph API)... If you're trying to get acces token for Microsoft Graph, then use `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` .. you can read more here for comparison https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

Comment: Why do you want to use Azure Government Web App? You want to get access token to call graph api, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview).

Answer (score 1):

since this was tagged azure-gov I presume the App Service is running in Azure Government? If so, what AAD authority are you specifying in the authentication context or /config/authsettings when calling Graph? If it's in Azure Gov, and you're planning to authenticate Azure Gov users, the AAD authority should be login.microsoftonline.us. What was the HTTP response to the request?

Also, as others have mentioned there are two "Graph" APIs (Azure AD Graph and Microsoft Graph) available at the moment. Microsoft Graph will ultimately replace Azure AD Graph but for now either can be used.

The resource uri for AAD Graph in Azure Gov, for now, is the same as Azure Public: graph.windows.net.

The resource uri for Microsoft Graph in Azure Gov, however, is graph.microsoft.us compared to graph.microsoft.com in Azure Public.

Comment: sorry i don't know why the post is tagged w/ Azure Gov, I think Marc came in and added that tag. But this is an Azure Web app. I am just looking for ways to get the Access token with Easy Auth? Apollogize for the confusion, i will edit my question and make it more clear

Comment: Got it, no problem. Still, some of my questions apply. Did you capture an exception during the authentication request? What was the HTTP response? There's not much detail present to discern what could be the reason for no access token.

Comment: There were no errors, but access token were not presented? I can put up a step by step of what I did in more detail

Comment: And your calls to graph executed correctly, containing the data you requested?

Comment: I can't access graph without an access token, right?

Comment: What I am trying to archive here, is to get access token to Ms Graph. My assumption is that, since i am already authenticated via `Azure App Service Authentication` with my registered app that has access to Graph, I can get **access token** from /.auth/me or from the header. Is that impossible/incorrect?

Comment: Correct, Graph requires an access token which is why I asked about any errors observed. Have you configured the app registration for your app service with a credential to authenticate itself to AAD and Graph? Then, have you assigned/requested the right permissions (And consented depending on which permissions were requested) from Graph? To be clear, you don't get an access token from authenticating to your app. Access tokens get issued when you try to access AAD protected resources, such as Graph. So, if you're checking for an access token prior to access Graph, you will not see one.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My app has delegate permission to access Azure Graph, is that enough?

Comment: *Should* be enough, but this is where you need to be very precise on what you mean by Graph. If you've delegated permissions to your app to Microsoft Graph, then the resource uri should be graph.microsoft.com. If you've delegated permissions to your app to Windows Azure Active Directory (Which is AAD Graph) then the resource uri should be graph.windows.net. Make sure you're using the right resource uri with what API you delegated access to. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bernie, doesn't seems to work. Looks like I will have to implement this differently...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191109/discussion-between-bernie-msft-and-ringo).

Comment: @Ringo - can you please write final solution here / or anything to achieve it

Comment: @Var i resolved the issue by storing an API key in our keyvault on the server side, then use the api key to get the access token. :(